# How to display a list of items horizontally in Silverlight with a separator?

Tags: silverlight

I'd like to know if there is a Silverlight control that allows me to display a list of items horizontally with a separator between each pair of items.

For example, suppose this is my list of items:

```
int[] items = new[] { 42, 43, 44, 45 };
```

then I want them to be rendered like this:

```
42 -> 43 -> 44 -> 45
```

This is just an example, in reality the items are objects that I'd like to bind to a template and the separator should be an image (or anything else). And in my case, the items are rendered as an element inside an `ItemsControl`.

Seems rather simple, but I can't find a good way to do this.

Kind regards,
Ronald

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `StackPanel` with horizontal orientation, and add sequences of number (in a `TextBox` control) + separator (as an `Image` control) as you need it.

Comment: I was actually hoping there would be a standard control that I could use for this, but I suppose such a control does not exist?

Comment: None that I know about, but anyway implementing a solution based on StackPanel is really easy, see the answer from Erez.

Comment: The problem is that the rendering of my items happens inside a DataTemplate inside an ItemsControl. So I wouldn't know when to add my items to the StackPanel.

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="333" Width="454">
    <Window.Resources>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Name="myStackPanel">
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and the Code Behind:

```
     int[] items = new[] { 42, 43, 44, 45 };

        myStackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        foreach (int item in items)
        {
            TextBlock txtNum = new TextBlock();
            txtNum.Text = item.ToString();

            TextBlock txtSeperator = new TextBlock(); // or image, as you wish
            txtSeperator.Text = "->";

            myStackPanel.Children.Add(txtNum);
            myStackPanel.Children.Add(txtSeperator);
        }
```

Comment: But what if I do not want a TextBlock to render my items but a custom template. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Can a custom IValueConverter be implemented where it checks the bound item against the collection it is bound to, and dependent on the index return either visibility.visible or visibility.collapsed?